# Why doesn't the TypeID of a variable equal the TypeID of the decayed type?

Tags: c++, generic-programming

To translate the question to C++ code, why doesn't

`typeid(T) == typeid(typename std::decay<T>::type)`

always evaluate to true? (In my tests, sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.)

According to the [typeid documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)...

> [typeid is] Used where the dynamic type of a polymorphic object must be known and for static type identification.

And the [documentation for decay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) provides this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename U>
struct decay_equiv : 
std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, U>::type 
{};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
          << decay_equiv<int, int>::value << '\n'
          << decay_equiv<int&, int>::value << '\n'
          << decay_equiv<int&&, int>::value << '\n'
          << decay_equiv<const int&, int>::value << '\n'
          << decay_equiv<int[2], int*>::value << '\n'
          << decay_equiv<int(int), int(*)(int)>::value << '\n';
}
```

And the output is:

```
true
true
true
true
true
true
```

So, if the `is_same` meta-function says they're the same types, then why doesn't typeid seem to agree?

Comment: Um... How about: becuase `typeid` is explictly and deliberately specified *not to decay* its argument?

Comment: @AnT Then how can `typeid` know the polymorphic type of the variable?

Comment: @Dovahkiin Do you have a test case where `is_same<A, B>::value` and `typeid(A) == typeid(B)` disagree?

Comment: @Dovahkiin: I don't understand where you see the connection between dynamic type and type decay. These are two unrelated concepts. `typeid` is specified not to decay types. `typeid` is specified to return dynamic type of polymorphis classes. That's all there is to it. Where's the problem?

Comment: @Sebastian Redl: That's easy: `int` vs. `const int`. Not `is_same`, but same `typeid`.

Comment: @SebastianRedl `const void* const`

Comment: @ant wrong way around?

Comment: @dova please be extremely specific.  Provide actual code you expect to behave one way, how you expect it to behave, how it does behave.  Your question above is "there exists" **without saying what** or what tests it fails exactly.  Edit actual types and expressions that do not behave the way you think they should.  [Mcve]

Comment: @Yakk: Um... No. Why? See for yourself: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e5e7a6a789f2d82

Comment: @AnT Shouldn't it be something like `std::is_same<std::decay_t<const int>, int>::value` accordingly with the question?

Comment: @skypjack: I was responding to Sebastian Red's request in the comments above. It is quite specific.

Comment: @AnT Oh, sorry, didn't follow exactly the trail of comments.

Comment: @AnT Ok, so I formulated this wrong. In line with the last question in the OP's post, I'm looking for cases where is_same says they're the same, but typeid comparison says they're different. (Interesting about top level const not changing the typeid, though quite logical also.)